# Where is the body in a nodejs http.get response?

Tags: node.js, http

I'm reading the docs at http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#http.request, but for some reason, I can't seem to to actually find the body/data attribute on the returned, finished  response object.

```
> var res = http.get({host:'www.somesite.com', path:'/'})

> res.finished
true

> res._hasBody
true
```

It's finished (http.get does that for you), so it should have some kind of content. But there's no body, no data, and I can't read from it. Where is the body hiding?

Comment: Since none of the answers mention how you'll know when the `data` events are done.. have your `res` listen for `"end"` (http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#event_end_)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

#### Edit: replying to self 6 years later

The [*await* keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) is the best way to get a response from an HTTP request, avoiding callbacks and `.then()`

**You'll also need to use an HTTP client that returns Promises.** `http.get()` still returns a Request object, so that won't work.

- `fetch` is a low level client, that is both available from npm and nodeJS 17 onwards.
- `superagent` is a mature HTTP clients that features more reasonable defaults including simpler query string encoding, properly using mime types, JSON by default, and other common HTTP client features.
- `axios` is also quite popular and has similar advantages to `superagent`

`await` will wait until the Promise has a value - in this case, an HTTP response! Modern JS supports await top level too, so you can skip needing `async function` wrappers.

```js
import superagent from "superagent";

const response = await superagent.get("https://www.google.com");
console.log(response.text);
```

Using await, control **simply passes onto the next line** once the promise returned by `superagent.get()` has a value.

Comment: Good point Vince I'll edit the answer to make it cleaner I'm using an HTTP client that supports Promises.

Comment: Note that superagent is also quite bloated: https://packagephobia.com/result?p=superagent

Comment: @JackGiffin Sure, that's because it's old. Newer clients wrap fetch (so they're smaller) and add sensible defaults (so they're more convenient than fetch)

Answer (score 189):

[http.request](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.request) docs contains example how to receive body of the response through handling `data` event:

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/upload',
  method: 'POST'
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

[http.get](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.10/api/http.html#http.get) does the same thing as http.request except it calls `req.end()` automatically.

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/index.html'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  res.on("data", function(chunk) {
    console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: For some reason, I had to add `res.setEncoding('utf8');` to the http.get example. Otherwise I didn't get HTML in the `chunk` variable.

Comment: @SSHThis that's because they were Buffer objects containing raw data. If you wanted strings from them you could also use chunk.toString(), optionally passing toString and encoding. That said, setEncoding is likely more efficient.

Comment: "data" event might be called multiple times and you will get the content piece by piece. Example does not show how to glue them together.

Comment: @tfmontague. Agreed! Surprising... so many upvotes for an answer that is flawed at its very foundation.

Comment: @tfmontague:  `POST requests typically use a response body, not GET.` Post *request* have a body and GET *request* does not, but a GET *response* can have a body.

Comment: @Cyrbil - I've redacted my original comment. I don't know enough about responses and event emitter to provide a solid argument here. Also don't have the time at the moment; I'll try to write back in a few days.

Comment: @yojimbo87 Hi I am trying to implement http.request. My code is the same as yours but I am getting an error: "No Access-Controll-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." May I know if you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Huiting Hi, you might be running into CORS issue - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: your answer `http.get` worked for me but instead of `host`,`port`,`path` iam using `url` like this `{url:'http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg'}` it giving me an error. How can solve it if that image url is not found i want to catch that response status code @yojimbo87

Comment: it's good to know that if you try to perform req.write() on a GET request, you won't get a response and the server won't receive what you were trying to send via req.write().

Answer (score 171):

I also want to add that the `http.ClientResponse` returned by `http.get()` has an `end` event, so here is another way that I receive the body response:

```
var options = {
  host: 'www.google.com',
  port: 80,
  path: '/index.html'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  var body = '';
  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    body += chunk;
  });
  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log(body);
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that! The 'end' event was crucial for me as I had to process the response body as a whole, rather than in chunks.

Comment: `http.ClientResponse` isn't returned by `http.get()` `http.ClientRequest` is, according to both the current documentation and the documentation linked to by the original poster.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#httpgetoptions-callback

Answer (score 26):

The `data` event is fired multiple times with 'chunks' of the body as they are downloaded and an `end` event when all chunks have been downloaded.

With Node supporting [Promises](https://www.javascripture.com/Promise) now, I created a simple wrapper to return the concatenated chunks through a Promise:

```
const httpGet = url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(url, res => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let body = ''; 
      res.on('data', chunk => body += chunk);
      res.on('end', () => resolve(body));
    }).on('error', reject);
  });
};
```

You can call it from an async function with:

```
const body = await httpGet('http://www.somesite.com');
```

Answer (score 16):

The body is not fully stored as part of the response, the reason for this is because the body can contain a very large amount of data, if it was to be stored on the response object, the program's memory would be consumed quite fast.

Instead, Node.js uses a mechanism called [Stream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/stream.html). This mechanism allows holding only a small part of the data and allows the programmer to decide if to fully consume it in memory or use each part of the data as its flowing.

There are multiple ways how to fully consume the data into memory, since `HTTP Response` is a readable stream, all readable methods are available on the `res` object

1. listening to the `"data"` event and saving the chunks passed to the callback

   ```
   const chunks = []

   res.on("data", (chunk) => {
       chunks.push(chunk)
   });

   res.on("end", () => {
       const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
   });
   ```

When using this approach you do not interfere with the behavior of the stream and you are only gathering the data as it is available to the application.

2. using the `"readble"` event and calling `res.read()`

   ```
   const chunks = [];

   res.on("readable", () => {
      let chunk;
      while(null !== (chunk = res.read())){
          chunks.push(chunk)
      }
   });

   res.on("end", () => {
       const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
   });
   ```

When going with this approach you are fully in charge of the stream flow and until `res.read` is called no more data will be passed into the stream.

3. using an async iterator

   ```
   const chunks = [];

   for await (const chunk of readable) {
       chunks.push(chunk);
   } 

   const body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
   ```

This approach is similar to the `"data" event` approach. It will just simplify the scoping and allow the entire process to happen in the same scope.

While as described, it is possible to fully consume data from the response it is always important to keep in mind if it is actually necessary to do so. In many cases, it is possible to simply direct the data to its destination without fully saving it into memory.

Node.js read streams, including HTTP response, have a built-in method for doing this, this method is called `pipe`. The usage is quite simple, `readStream.pipe(writeStream);`.

for example:

If the final destination of your data is the file system, you can simply open a write stream to the file system and then `pipe` the data to ts destination.

```
const { createWriteStream } = require("fs");
const writeStream = createWriteStream("someFile");
res.pipe(writeStream);
```

Comment: This well explains why I can't see the response body in the VSC debugger.  Thank you!

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer as it succinctly describes how to use the native streaming functionality in Node, rather than requiring an additional dependency.

Comment: This has to be the accepted answer! The `Buffer.concat(chunks)` is the real trick here.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to use .get you can do it like this

```
http.get(url, function(res){
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        console.log(chunk);
    });

});
```

Comment: The other examples gave me what looked like hex values when I didn't included text with the chunk response. Setting the encoding displayed the JSON document I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @CollinMcGuire that's because they were Buffer objects containing raw data. If you wanted strings from them you could also use `chunk.toString()`, optionally passing `toString` and encoding. That said, `setEncoding` is likely more efficient.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add a listener to the request because node.js works asynchronous like that:

```
request.on('response', function (response) {
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Just an improved version to ***nkron*** responce.

```
const httpGet = url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(url, res => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      const body = [];
      res.on('data', chunk => body.push(chunk));
      res.on('end', () => resolve(body.join('')));
    }).on('error', reject);
  });
};
```

Appending chunks in an string[] is better for memory usage, the join(''), will allocate
new memory only once.

Answer (score 2):

Needle module is also good, here is an example which uses `needle` module

```
var needle = require('needle');

needle.get('http://www.google.com', function(error, response) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200)
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the body of the response from the return value of `http.get()`.

[`http.get()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) doesn't return a response object. It returns the request object ([`http.clientRequest`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest)). So, there isn't any way to get the body of the response from the return value of `http.get()`.

I know it's an old question, but reading [the documentation you linked to](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.0/api/http.html#http.request) shows that this was the case even when you posted it.

Answer (score 0):

A portion of Coffee here:

```
# My little helper
read_buffer = (buffer, callback) ->
  data = ''
  buffer.on 'readable', -> data += buffer.read().toString()
  buffer.on 'end', -> callback data

# So request looks like
http.get 'http://i.want.some/stuff', (res) ->
  read_buffer res, (response) ->
    # Do some things with your response
    # but don't do that exactly :D
    eval(CoffeeScript.compile response, bare: true)
```

And compiled

```
var read_buffer;

read_buffer = function(buffer, callback) {
  var data;
  data = '';
  buffer.on('readable', function() {
    return data += buffer.read().toString();
  });
  return buffer.on('end', function() {
    return callback(data);
  });
};

http.get('http://i.want.some/stuff', function(res) {
  return read_buffer(res, function(response) {
    return eval(CoffeeScript.compile(response, {
      bare: true
    }));
  });
});
```