# how process response object from Google Places API - placesPhoto

Tags: node.js, google-places-api

I am writing a simple wrapper in node.js which calls Goole Places API and gets a photo using photo_reference. When I run this and process the request from Postman it works but does not display photo itself. In the code below mapsClient.placesPhoto does return a huge response with many tags. Its not just raw image data. My question is how do I extract image or image data from googleResp object and send it back to client?

```
var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
  key: 'xyz' 
});

app.post('/getGooglePlacePhoto/:photoref', function(req, res){

    googleMapsClient.placesPhoto({
        photoreference: req.params["photoref"],
        maxwidth: 70,
        maxheight: 70
    }, function(err, googleResp){
        if (!err) {
            debug('got response from google');
            res.set('Content-Type','image/jpeg');
            debug(googleResp.body);
            res.send(200, googleResp.body);
        } else {
                debug(err);
                res.send(409, err);
                return;
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: below is partial response I get when I print entire googleResp object. Does the buffer contain image? and if so how do I access the buffer in node.js    IncomingMessage { _readableState: ReadableState { objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 16384, buffer: [ <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e1 00 2a 45 78 69 66 00 00 49 49 2a 00 08 00 00 00 01 00 31 01 02 00 07 00 00 00 1a 00 ... > ], length: 864,

Comment: Yes, the buffer there looks like a JPEG, or at least the start of one, judging from the initial bytes: (ff d8 ff e0).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968448/where-is-body-in-a-nodejs-http-get-response might help.