# Getting the URL of Google Place Photo from a GoogleMapsClient response

Tags: javascript, google-maps, express

I'm building an API endpoint which will return details and a single photo of a Google place using express.js and [Node.js client library for Google Maps API Web Services](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js). The endpoint below returns details of a place and I'm having trouble retrieving the URL of a photo. Below is the code in question.

There are two requests to the google maps client:

1. Get place details based on `req.params.id` and the details contain a `photos` array
2. Get photo using the `photo_reference` from above

   ```
   var googleMapsClient = require('@google/maps').createClient({
     key: 'mykeyhere',
     Promise: Promise
   });

   exports.getGglPlace = function(req, res) {

   googleMapsClient.place({
        placeid: req.params.id
   }).asPromise()
   .then((response) => {
     var venue = response.json.result

     if (venue.photos[0]) {
       googleMapsClient.placesPhoto({
         photoreference: venue.photos[0].photo_reference,
         maxwidth: 200
       }).asPromise()
       .then((photo) => {

         console.log("Photo:", photo); // this returns a massive chunk of data which I think contains the actual image object also
         venue.photoURL = photo.url; // this doesn't work

         res.send(venue);
       })
       .catch((err)=>{
         console.log("Error Getting Photo!", err);
         res.send(venue);
       })
     } else {
       res.send(venue);
     }
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     res.send(404);
   })
   }
   ```

Any idea how to obtain the URL from the response which is called `photo` in the code above?

If I try going to the API directly through the browser or Postman, the URL gets redirected to the actual source URL of the image, which is what I want to add to my `venue` object.

API request example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CmRaAAAA8NPP1nJJ7RCzcQDGUrpBHJXlzlQkN74dcyQJ2ytVpeYIu47sR-8dfCjke1J5exP-HpkayaXOc26ShsVKkXOaJZBOdpmExUfCzUTIBN3x0uPfR5Nt3PnN-a3GoRVZ7YxKEhBvqXF356Tn9mBJ7lA_JQ_7GhQMKvZkOk-Rs9knsansx5yuhfIvsQ&sensor=false&key=mykeyhere

Redirects to (this is what I want `photo.url` to return): https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPVD12HA5FBnjmiqVLphYgjfPtIPydn4Ie-xGKr=s1600-w200

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. My first post here - sorry if I'm not clear enough with my question.

Comment: I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39508823/how-process-response-object-from-google-places-api-placesphoto), but it has no answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I solved it. It doesn't seem perfect, but it does the job.

The response contains a **req** section which has keys in there that I was able to use to build the URL. Specifically, the **`response.req.socket._host`** key and the **`response.req.path`** key.

Here is what it looks like in my code (where `photo` is the response from google API)

`venue.photoURL = "https://" + photo.req.socket._host + photo.req.path;`

`photo.req.socket._host` gives me *lh3.googleusercontent.com*

`photo.req.path` gives me */p/AF1QipPVD12HA5FBnjmiqVLphYgjfPtIPydn4Ie-xGKr=s1600-w200*

Results of the constructed URL to the photo is: `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/AF1QipPVD12HA5FBnjmiqVLphYgjfPtIPydn4Ie-xGKr=s1600-w200`

Comment: Yeah I think this works, but it's incredibly tedious. I wonder, anyone knows why this library has such a problematic implementation? This doesn't seem friendly at all to the 3rd party developer consuming the Google Places Photo API

Comment: you can get the url without constructing it, like this: `response.req._redirectable._options.href`. If this does not work for you try `response.request._redirectable._options.href`, because some libraries name the response object **`req`**, others **`request`** (Axios uses `request`). See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

## you can do this

#### with [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```js
axios.get(url).then(res => {
  console.log(res.request._redirectable._options.href));
});
```

#### with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```
fetch(url).then(res => {
  console.log(res.url);
});
```

**IMPORTANT**: make sure you have the package you use installed and required and make sure the url you use works in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The response of a successful Place Photo request will be an image, not an object literal.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos

The way the browse knows how to redirect to the photo is via a header. If you check out the response you will see it returns a 302 (redirect) and follows the response header `location`. You should be able to grab that header in express via:

```
res.get('location');
// => "image url"
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do it. On my end response returns `status: 200` and  `.get` is not recognized. Moreover, there is nothing in the response that I found that's called "location".

Comment: Here is an example of the header that comes in the response (called photo in the code above): 
https://codepad.co/snippet/eoXu0bzS#_=_

Answer (score 0):

This code below works on my clientside JS project. Thus, I am able to retrieve place data and its photos as useful link and push it into img src on my html. Maybe it could be useful.

```
   var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
   service.nearbySearch({
        location: latlonNearby,
        radius: 500,
        type: NearbyTypes,
        keyword: ['kafe', 'caffe']
   }, callback);
   function callback(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
           // I retrieved first added photo "photos[0]" //
           var placePhotoUrl = results[i].photos[0].getUrl({maxWidth:640}); 
           console.log(placePhotoUrl);
           // Then Do Whatever You Want with this placePhotoUrl //
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: getUrl works only in the client javascript, not on the server side

Answer (score 0):

If you use postman, you must turn of settings->automatically follow redirects, then you'll se something like this

```
   <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/p/blahblah">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Follow url to find image.