# AWS Lambda web service calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, web-services, aws-lambda

I managed to get the following working in Lambda (not throwing errors) but how can I see the actual response JSON?

```
var https = require('https');

exports.handler = function (event, context) {
  https.get('https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/FRED/M12015USM144NNBR.json?  api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', function (result) {
    console.log('Success, with: ' + result.statusCode);
    context.done(null);
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Error, with: ' + err.message);
    context.done("Failed");
  });
};
```

Comment: Where do you want to "see" it? It's in the `result` object. Log it or pass it to the `context.done()` function.

Answer (score 0):

HMMM... isn't (result) comes back with the object contains with the request response from data event?

[Where is body in a nodejs http.get response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968448/where-is-body-in-a-nodejs-http-get-response)