# Drilling into API elements from returned response in node.js

Tags: node.js, api

Im new to node.js and consuming apis, I'm trying to access the returned `'access_token'` but when I do `res.access_token` I get an undefined...any idea what I should be doing?

> My node.js file

```
const https = require("https");

const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    host : 'api.com',
    path: '/oauth2/token'
        +'?grant_type=client_credentials'
        +'&client_id=*******'
        +'&client_secret=***********',
    headers:
    {
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
      Flow: 'application',
    }
  };

const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

    res.on('data', d => {
      process.stdout.write(d)
    })
})

req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
})

req.end()
```

> Which returns the following

```
statusCode: 200
{"access_token":"********","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":7199}
```

Answer (score 0):

That in that snippet, you have a callback function which has a res parameter. That is the Response object. What you are looking for is called the response body. There is a similar question that has a good answer which will likely provide the info you need.
[Get body from the data event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6968669/2255316)