# How to get the request body off of a https get request using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, https, get

I am making a get request using https and aws4 in node js. I know it works because my post request works, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to get the GET request body. I need to put the request body of the GET response in a variable.

The StatusCurrent function is where i need to get the response sent back by the GET Request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const Alexa = require("ask-sdk-core");
var https = require("https");
var aws4 = require("aws4");

function request(opts) {
  https
    .request(opts, function (res) {
      res.pipe(process.stdout);
      // IS THIS WHERE I GET THE REQUEST BODY, BUT HOW
      // I NEED TO PUT IT IN A VARIABLE
    })
    .end(opts.body || "");
}

function lightbulb(status) {
  var load = JSON.stringify({
    state: {
      desired: {
        on: status,
      },
    },
  });

  request(
    aws4.sign(
      {
        hostname: "obsf-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        service: "iotdata",
        region: "us-east-1",
        method: "POST",
        path: "/things/esp8266_7F3B95/shadow",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json0",
        },
        body: load,
      },
      {
        secretAccessKey: "",
        accessKeyId: "obsf",
      }
    )
  );
}

function statusCurrent() {
  request(
    aws4.sign(
      {
        hostname: "obsf-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        service: "iotdata",
        region: "us-east-1",
        method: "GET",
        path: "/things/esp8266_7F3B95/shadow",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json0",
        },
      },
      {
        secretAccessKey: "",
        accessKeyId: "osbf",
      }
    )
  );
}
```

based on the answer this is the request repsonse I get back but I can't access the state with `body.state`

```
{
    "state": {
        "desired": {
            "on": false
        },
        "reported": {
            "ota": {
                "fw_version": "1.0",
                "fw_id": "20201123-145524",
                "mac": "4A3FDA7F3B95",
                "device_id": "esp8266_7F3B95",
                "app": "indoor-doorbell",
                "arch": "esp8266",
                "message": "idle",
                "status": 0,
                "is_committed": true,
                "partition": 0,
                "progress_percent": 0
            },
            "ram_total": 52672,
            "ram_free": 28892,
            "uptime": 0,
            "btnCount": 2,
            "on": false
        }
    },
    "metadata": {
        "desired": {
            "on": {
                "timestamp": 1606258639
            }
        },
        "reported": {
            "ota": {
                "fw_version": {
                    "timestamp": 1606185982
                },
                "fw_id": {
                    "timestamp": 1606185982
                },
                "mac": {
                    "timestamp": 1606185982
                },
                "device_id": {
                    "timestamp": 1606185982
                },
                "app": {
                    "timestamp": 1606185982
                },
                "arch": {
                    "timestamp": 1606185982
                },
                "message": {
                    "timestamp": 1606218681
                },
                "status": {
                    "timestamp": 1606218681
                },
                "is_committed": {
                    "timestamp": 1606218681
                },
                "partition": {
                    "timestamp": 1606218681
                },
                "progress_percent": {
                    "timestamp": 1606218681
                }
            },
            "ram_total": {
                "timestamp": 1606218681
            },
            "ram_free": {
                "timestamp": 1606171272
            },
            "uptime": {
                "timestamp": 1606258639
            },
            "btnCount": {
                "timestamp": 1606258639
            },
            "on": {
                "timestamp": 1606258639
            }
        }
    },
    "version": 225030,
    "timestamp": 1606265545
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const httpGet = url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get(url, res => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let body = ''; 
      res.on('data', chunk => body += chunk);
      res.on('end', () => resolve(body));
    }).on('error', reject);
  });
};
```

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244236/2142490

I'd expect it to be the same for https

**UPDATE**: so i'd try

```
function request(opts) {
  https
    .request(opts, function (res) {

      // IS THIS WHERE I GET THE REQUEST BODY, BUT HOW
      // I NEED TO PUT IT IN A VARIABLE
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let body = ''; 
      res.on('data', chunk => body += chunk);
      res.on('end', () => {
          
          console.log(body);
          let json = JSON.parse(body);
          console.log(json.state);

      }
    })
    .end(opts.body || "");
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am trying to decipher this against my question, where do I place this. I have my aws4.sign wrapper in a request function? Could you give me a hint as to how I would do this with the aws4, I'm a little lost. I had seen that answer and it wasn't helping me

Comment: How would I implement the Promise with what I have and do the res.on('data') part I'm sorry but I dont quite follow. I don't know what to add or remove from my code so I am a little stuck here

Comment: i updated my answer, adding my assumption on how the code would have to look like

Comment: It seems to be working, and I will choose your answer, but for some reason when I try to traverse the object I get undefined, and I ahve tried JSON.parse(body...) any idea why this may be?

Comment: I have added the json response I get back. This is weird, it seems like it would just work

Comment: If the "body" string holds the response you expected, your initial problem should be solved. Print out the body string. It should then be visible by eye if its a JSON string.

Comment: I have updated my answer. There is how i would handle the body string if its JSON and access the .state property

Comment: You should not have your AWS secretAccessKey etc. visible here.

Comment: I wrote random characters in all the secret key area, should have just wrote random or something